# Why does cleaning up after copy in Excel VBA take so long and how do you fix it?

Tags: excel, vba

The code below takes about 15 seconds to iterate through the 500 rows that are copied and then another 15 seconds between setting the status to "Done with copy, showing msgbox" and actually showing the message box.

1.) Is there a faster way to do this copy (the actual use case has been simplified, for other reasons I do need to iterate through the source sheet and copy a range of values to the target sheet)?

2.) What is causing the application to take so long between iterating through the cells and showing the msgbox?

```
Sub CopyValues()

    Dim srcSheet As Worksheet
    Dim dstSheet As Worksheet
    
    Set srcSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set dstSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    
    currentRow = 5
    lastRow = 500
    
    For r = 2 To lastRow
        With srcSheet
            .Range(.Cells(r, 1), .Cells(r, 2)).Copy Destination:=dstSheet.Cells(currentRow, 1)
        End With
        Application.StatusBar = "Row " & r & " of " & lastRow
        currentRow = currentRow + 1
    Next r
    Application.StatusBar = "Done with copy, showing msgbox"
    MsgBox "Done."

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are not copying the entire range at once? `.Range(."A2:B500").Copy Destination:=dstSheet.Range("A5:B503")`?

Comment: Unless you are copying formulas and/or formats, simply `target.value = source.value` is faster (where `source` and `target` are the entire ranges -- as @cybernetic.nomad mentions, you don't need to do this cell by cell).

Comment: I would use lookups at the destination to import values without any VBA at all.

Comment: Are the destination cells used in formulas or have conditional formatting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up saving files as csv and then processing using another language (in this case Java using Apache's csv parsing library).

Classes used:

```
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVParser;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVPrinter;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVRecord;
```

Maven Dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. There is a faster way, even if you need to loop. The idea is to pull the data into an array, then edit however you need by looping into another array. Then finally send this Resulting array back to the workbook. For example:

```vb
Sub CopyValues2()
    Dim srcSheet As Worksheet
    Dim dstSheet As Worksheet
    Dim aResult()
    
    Set srcSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set dstSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    
    lastrow = 500
    
    ary = srcSheet.Range("A1:B" & lastrow).Value
    ReDim aResult(1 To lastrow, 1 To 2) 'size result to the size of original
    
    'illustrate looping over the values (although not needed for simple copying
    For i = 1 To lastrow
      'copy to a new array
      aResult(i, 1) = ary(i, 1)
      aResult(i, 2) = ary(i, 2)
    Next
    
    dstSheet.Range("A1:B" & lastrow).Value = aResult
End Sub
```

2. The application was taking a long time because there is a time-lag everytime it switches from running VBA to placing the data into cells. The fix reduces the number of switches.

Comment: You are setting srcSheet values to dstSheet values

Comment: Yes, I was, I then noticed that he requires looping, and so I edited so it now illustrates a faster way, even with looping.